# Result from db, shall I sort them with AJ or MYSQL Query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, angularjs

When retrieving data from db I would like to order them by column and sort them DESC or ASC. My SQL query does what I want. But I would like to know the fastest way of doing this?

The thing is that I think the user shouldn't update whole the page when changing the order or sort options. Thats why I think it is better to sort them with AJ. So everything is instantly. What do you think? AJ or shall I order and sort directly when retrieving from the db?

Thanks

Comment: If you can afford losing the sorting functionality, say, under Opera Mini, AJ sort is just fine.  Otherwise, you'll either need multiple implementations and browser detection or just always sort on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

For  fetching the data on the first page load and sorting it as fast as possible, it's better to get the database to do it so that it can use indexes. This of course assumes that you have created indexes on the appropriate columns. Also if you are only displaying the first `n` rows then it's better to get the database to do the sorting and return only the first `n` rows to the client rather than giving the client a copy of the entire database.

On the other hand if you have already fetched all rows to the client and just want to apply a different ordering then it may be faster to do the sorting on the client to avoid an extra database hit.